# Calculate Time Difference in C#:

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two string variables such as StartTime and EndTime. I need to Calculate the TotalTime by subtracting the EndTime with StartTime.

The Format of StartTime and EndTime is as like follows:

```
    StartTime = "08:00 AM";
    EndTime = "04:00 PM";
```

TotalTime in Hours and Mins Format. 
How to calculate this using C#?

Comment: Use DateTime.Parse, DateTime.ParseExact, DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact to parse the times. Then substract as usual and you have a TimeSpan object with the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert them to `DateTime` and substract one from other to get `TimeSpan`.

```
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Parse("08:00 AM");

DateTime EndTime  = DateTime.Parse("04:00 PM"); // It converts this to 1600.

TimeSpan ts = EndTime - StartTime;
```

When i run above code it is giving me

```
ts.Days              // 0
ts.Hours             // 8
ts.Milliseconds      // 0
ts.Minutes           // 0
ts.Seconds           // 0
ts.Ticks             // 288000000000
ts.TotalDays         // 0.3333333333333333331
ts.TotalHours        // 8.0
ts.TotalMilliseconds // 28800000.0
ts.TotalMinutes      // 480.0
ts.TotalSeconds      // 28800.0
```

to get what you want.

Comment: How to consider AM and PM while using TimeSpan?

Comment: Timespan is time range like a stopwatch which tells how much time has passed since stopwatch was started which in your case is starttime

Answer (score 6):

You should convert your strings to `DateTime` and use `TimeSpan` to calculate the difference

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(StartTime);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(EndTime);
TimeSpan ts = dt.Subtract(dt2);
```

Something like the above. You might need `ParseExact` instead of `Parse`

For your sample times, `ts.ToString()` will return a string `"08:00:00"` giving hours, minutes and seconds difference

Comment: How to consider AM and PM while using TimeSpan?

Comment: @thevan You don't. `TimeSpan` is not a "current" time, it is a time range - a range of 18 hours is neither "AM" or "PM" and cannot logically be so. The only time you will need to consider AM or PM is in the string during parsing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ParseExact` method to specify the exact format when you parse the strings to `DateTime` values, then subtract them to get a `TimeSpan` value:

```
string StartTime = "08:00 AM";
string EndTime = "04:00 PM";

DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(StartTime, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(EndTime, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeSpan diff = end - start;

Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalMinutes);
```

Output:

```
480
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string StartTime, EndTime;
StartTime = "08:00 AM"; 
EndTime = "04:00 PM"; 
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse(StartTime); 
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse(EndTime); 
TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

> Output : 08:00:00
>   The put is in Hrs:Min:Sec format.

thats What you needed. Right

Note:
endTime should come first while subtracting.